# typescript でアローによって定義されたメソッドはどうトランスパイルされますか？

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

typescript では、 javascript では許可されない記述方法がいくつか可能です。その中には、例えば以下に示すような arrow 関数を用いたメソッド定義があります。

```
class Foo {
  sayThis = () => console.log(this);
}

const foo = new Foo();
const sayThisFunction = foo.sayThis;
sayThisFunction();  // => Foo { sayThis: [Function] }
```

このように arrow としてクラスに定義された関数は、メソッドのような振る舞いをしていて、一方、 this はどのように呼び出しても、そのメソッドが所属しているオブジェクトに対して解決されているような振る舞いです。

これは、一見、どのようなコードに最終的に落ちているのかが、あまり自明ではないな、と思いました。

#### 質問

- 上記のように、アロー関数でメソッドを typescript にて定義したとき、それと同等のことを実現する javascript コードはどのようなものになりますか？

Comment: 実際にご自身で変換結果を見てみられてはどうでしょう?＞[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) ConfigからTargetをES5以前にすると、なかなか興味深い変換結果が見られます。私はJavaScriptの`this`についてそらで語れるほど頭には入ってないので、変換結果に対する解説を含めた回答の形にはできませんが。

Comment: ヒント： 当該のコードはTC39のプロポーザルで現在stage-3にある[class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)によるものです。たとえばこのコードは手元のChrome77ではそのまま同じ挙動をしています。クラスフィールドとして定義された変数はコンストラクタ内でフィールドを定義するのと同義(すでにコンストラクタがあるばあいはその最後におこなわれる)ですし、ある意味ESで同等のことを実現するコードはそのままでいけるともいえます(いや、まだstableにはなっていないのでいえませんね)。これだけでも回答としては十分な気もしたのですが散文なのでとりあえずコメントとして。